# MATLAB escaping parentheses

Tags: regex, matlab

I am quite exhausted as I have not found anything on MATLAB's website that suggests how to do this.

I have a set of strings e.g. `'AGB1129C(1)'`and trying to do a regexp on them so that all the strings ending with (1) and (2) can be separated. The problem is that I cannot find an escape character that does brackets (). Does anyone know what the escape character should be?

N.B. my regexp was `'[A-ZA-ZA-Z0-90-90-90-9]+\(1\)'`.

Comment: If you wanted to have letters and digits matched specifically, you would write `\w\w\w\d\d\d\d\d\(\1\)` or shorter: `\w{3}\d{5}\(1\)`

Comment: @Jonas          What I did was `'([A-ZA-Z0-90-9A-Z]+\(1\))'` It was alright :) your solution is also correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex syntax is incorrect (but `\` is proper escape character in MATLAB regexes). Try this sample:

```
>> regexp('AGB1129C(1)', '[A-Z0-9]+\(1\)')

ans =

 1
```

Comment: oh right! So the brackets actually group expressions together! Hmm...thanks for this...a very big help!

Comment: Grouping is covered here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-42884